# Macbook apps are suddenly gone

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, applications

I was updating Rider app from Jetbrains Toolbox and I went out for a couple of minutes and when I came back half of macbook apps were gone. There wasn't any error message on screen. Before this I had 10GB of free space now It says 30GB of free space. All of my other files (documents, music, pictures, downloaded files) are untouched. Does anyone know what is wrong?
I searched for deleted applications in finder and they weren't anywhere. I noticed that many of the deleted apps weren't installed from Appstore.
I'm using MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) and Catalina 10.15.4.
I restarted and did SMC Reset but none of them were helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check System Prefs > iCloud > iCloud Drive > Options… is Optimise Mac storage on?

Comment: I couldn't find Optimise storage in iCloud Drive. But I found it by clicking on manage (second picture) and it says "Completed". But isn't this for Apple TV movies and Tv shows?